# References on topological rings

Tags: reference-request, topological-groups, p-adic-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, formal-schemes

What is a good book on topological rings and modules?

I'm interested in topological rings and modules typically endowed with non-linear topologies, e.g.. non-linearly topologized normed rings.

I have some references at my disposal, but I would like to ask for some here, just in case.

Thanks.

*Current references*:

**Seth Warner**: Topological Rings.

**Bourbaki**, Éléments de Mathématique. Topologie Générale.

**Mihail Ursul**, Topological rings satisfying compactness conditions.

Comment: Andre Weil's basic number theory contains adelic rings (and related rings) which are important in number theory

Comment: Are you interested in topological *fields* as well?

Comment: I think that the (tag:reference-request]) tag would be suitable here. But already all 5 spots for tags are used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are 3 references that haven't been mentioned yet. I am not sure if the latter two would be of any use to you, but probably are worth a look.

- Arnautov, Glavatsky, Mikhalev - Introduction to the Theory of Topological Rings and Modules (1995)
- Prolla - Topics in Functional Analysis over Valued Division Rings (1982)
- Shell - Topological Fields and Near-Valuations (1990)